# how to get [Binary Data] value from a MSI file

Tags: python, windows-installer, binary-data

I am reading a MSI file using python **msilib** library. My aim is to extract [Binary Data] from Binary table and dump into a file. (Using ORCA tool, we can extract the binary data by double clicking [Binary Data] cell and write to a file)

I could not find any msilib  method to get binary data. It have method to get string data using Record.GetString(field). But as expected this is not working for [Binary Data] and give error.

Here is the code snippet

```
import msilib
# msi file path which is to be read
msiFilePath = "C:/msi/test.msi"
dbObj = msilib.OpenDatabase(msiFilePath, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)
sqlQuery = "select * from Binary"
view = dbObj.OpenView(sqlQuery)
view.Execute(None)
cur_record = viewObj.Fetch()
# In Binary table; Column no 1 have string data and Column # 2 have [Binary Data]
cur_record.GetString(2)
```

And on execution :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
cur_record.GetString(2)
_msi.MSIError: unknown error 70c
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 7):

[msilib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html) is [not fully featured](http://bugs.python.org/issue12026). Specifically, it can't read binary data.

Pygame hosts a more full featured and extensible (because it's written in Python with ctypes), [msidb](http://hg.pygame.org/pygame/src/2edb32f16576/msidb.py?at=msi). It doesn't seem to be covered in the pygame docs, but the source code is pretty straightforward.

The MSI API you need is `MsiRecordReadStream` which pygame.msidb wraps in `get_field_stream` which is used by its `Cursor` class.

Comment: @aberry, is there anything else I can do to make this answer more acceptable to you?